MariaDB Server Overloading

I have a docker host on which have multiple mariadb containers each for one application.
But I have one particular application, my main application which overload the server eachtime that I start it container. I have tried to truncate my largest tables and rebuild container plus volume but problem still persist.
I have been struggling on this issue for too many days now.
Can anyone have an idea?
my.cnf
[mysqld]
port = 7982
wait_timeout=60
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
max_connections=550
innodb_buffer_pool_size=20G
#innodb_log_file_size=2G
table_open_cache=4000
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
query_cache_type = OFF



#### These optimize the memory use of MySQL
#### http://www.tocker.ca/2014/03/10/configuring-mysql-to-use-minimal-memory.html
innodb_log_buffer_size=2097152
query_cache_size=0
key_buffer_size=8
thread_cache_size=0
host_cache_size=0
innodb_ft_cache_size=32000000 
innodb_ft_total_cache_size=160000000

# per thread or per operation settings
thread_stack=181920
sort_buffer_size=32K
read_buffer_size=8200
read_rnd_buffer_size=8200
max_heap_table_size=16K
tmp_table_size=1K
bulk_insert_buffer_size=0
join_buffer_size=128
net_buffer_length=1K
innodb_sort_buffer_size=64K

#settings that relate to the binary log (if enabled)
binlog_cache_size=4K
binlog_stmt_cache_size=4K

#
# This group is read both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]
# Port or socket location where to connect
# port = 3306
socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory

!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/


Dockerfile
FROM mariadb:10.11.3

RUN apt-get update -yq \
&& apt-get install vim -yq \
&& apt-get clean -y

EXPOSE 7982
COPY ./my.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf


Docker compose setup
services:
  doowebdb:
    container_name: doowebdb
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 7982:7982
    volumes:
      - doowebproddb:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./dbdump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    restart: always
    environment:
      MARIADB_DISABLE_UPGRADE_BACKUP: 1
      MARIADB_AUTO_UPGRADE: 0
      MARIADB_MYSQL_LOCALHOST_USER: true
      MYSQL_TCP_PORT: 7982
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD_HASH: "*623054527B8002016B33B71F87D8180A562F64CB"
      MARIADB_ROOT_HOST: localhost
      MARIADB_DATABASE: dappfinal
      MARIADB_USER: u_dappfinal2024
      MARIADB_PASSWORD_HASH: "*6CB164F09ECC0984080CC1A52001DEE4267A8E8B" 
    networks:
      - ddb_network


volumes:
  dbproddb: {}
networks:
  ddb_network:


Any help will be appreciated!
As you can see I dont have much process running. but processors are used at 100%.

Any help will be appreciated!

Multiple instances of MariaDB?  Why not just one?

This question is hard to answer because it's missing so much information.

What are the SQL queries? We only see a screenshot of truncated queries.

You said you truncated the largest tables, but are those the tables being queried in the queries that are running? I would guess not, based on the execution time shown in the processlist.

Are the queries that are running optimized with indexes? You haven't shown any table definitions, or EXPLAIN to show the optimization strategy for the queries. A common reason for overloaded servers is that queries are poorly optimized. Once you add indexes to support those specific queries, the load will probably get a lot better.

Is there a way the code that handles requests could be redesigned to cause less load on the database server? Is your code re-reading values it doesn't have to? No way to guess, because you haven't shown any code.


The process of optimizing a server is to identify where it's spending most of its time, and why those operations are taking so long. Or if the operations are individually fast, but there's just so many of them that in aggregate they create high load. Then try to make changes to the code or the database to reduce the load.
There are many ways you can do this, and choosing the best strategy depends on what the application needs to do. No one on this site knows that better than you do.
